# How to write Espresso view/data matchers in Appium Java Client?

Tags: java, kotlin, appium, android-espresso, appium-android

I am using Appium to test Android application and today I was instructed to switch from `UIAutomator2` to `Espresso` automator. I realized that it will not be so simple as just changing automator name.

As far as my searching go, Appium with `Espresso` automator have very little (almost none) documentation for writing selectors (view/data matchers) in Java/Kotlin.

I am trying to find out how to for example rewrite my current method for `search by text`. It looks like this:

```kotlin
(driver as AndroidDriver<*>).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().textContains(\"$text\")")
// Written for UIAutomator2
```

I tried:

```kotlin
(driver as AndroidDriver<*>).findElement(MobileBy.androidViewMatcher(Json().toJson(
    ImmutableMap.of(
        "name", "withText",
        "args", ImmutableList.of("<text>"),
    )
)))
```

But does not seems to work...

I see in `appium-espresso-driver` readme that I [can search by text and by much more](https://github.com/appium/appium-espresso-driver#element-location), but I cannot simply find a documentation how to send those commands to Appium Server trough `Appium java client`.

Any recommendations for docs, or help how to do it? Thanks